# Profinite completions and inverse limits

Tags: commutative-algebra, profinite-groups

The following questions are mainly curiosities; I recently came across the definitions of inverse limits and profinite completions, and below are two questions about them I could not answer myself. I don't think the questions are of any practical importance, but I would nonetheless like to get to the bottom of them so as to understand the concepts better.

**Question 1**: The profinite completion $\hat G$ of a group $G$ is defined as the inverse limit of its finite quotients ordered by inclusion and equipped with the canonical projection maps. If $G$ is finite, the profinite completion is isomorphic to $G$ itself; indeed, the inverse limit will consist of finite sequences of compatible elements of $G$, which are determined by the first entry, which is an element of the quotient $G / \{e\}$.

My question regards the case where $G$ is infinite. Is it possible to find a group $G$ with only a finite number of normal subgroups? In this case, the completion $\hat G$ will be isomorphic to the biggest quotient $G / N$, where $N \trianglelefteq G$. As $G$ is infinite, $G$ itself will not be a finite quotient in this case. Of course $\hat G$ is supposed to contain $G$, so I am not sure if this case exists, however I have not been able to come up with an argument why not.

**Question 2**: This question concerns the cardinality of inverse limits. Given an inverse system $(G_i, \phi_{ij})$ for $i,j$ in some infinite indexing set $I$, the inverse limit $\displaystyle\lim_{\longleftarrow} G_i$ is a subgroup of $\prod_{i \in I} G_i$. This product is always uncountable (assuming the $G_i$ are non-trivial), as Cantor's diagonal argument shows. My question is whether or not there are non-trivial examples of the inverse limit being countable. Again, my intuition says this can't happen, but I'm missing the tools to prove this.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes, for example there are infinite simple groups, such as $PSL_2(\mathbb{R})$. The profinite completion of any such group is trivial. More generally, a group $G$ does not always embed in its profinite completion; this is true iff $G$ is [residually finite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residually_finite_group). (You forgot the condition that the normal subgroups have finite index.)
2. No, it's either finite or uncountable. There are several ways to show it: one is to use the existence of a [Haar measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haar_measure) of total measure $1$ on any compact (Hausdorff) abelian group, which is impossible if the group is countable.